# Error while binding a socket : NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"

Tags: objective-c, gcdasyncsocket

I'm trying to implement [GCDAsyncSocket](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket) to mac os x (Mojave 10.14.3) application to listen data from localhost:port.

The problem is no matter what port I choose I always get this error:

```
Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"
UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Operation not permitted, 
NSLocalizedFailureReason=Error in bind() function}
```

I've already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47797446/nsposixerrordomain-when-binding-to-socket-on-macos-10-12), but it didn't work.

Here is my implementation in **AppDelegate.mm**:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    listenSocket = [[GCDAsyncSocket alloc] initWithDelegate:(id<GCDAsyncSocketDelegate>) self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
    connectedSockets = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1];
    isRunning = NO;
    NSError *err = nil;
    if (![listenSocket connectToHost:@"localhost" onPort:12345 error:&err]){
        NSLog(@"I goofed: %@", err);
    }
}

-(void)getData{
    if(!isRunning)
    {
        int port = 12345;
        if(port < 0 || port > 65535)
        {
            port = 0;
        }
        NSError *error = nil;
        if(![listenSocket acceptOnPort:port error:&error])
        {
            NSLog(@"error: %@", FORMAT(@"Error starting server: %@", error));
            return;
        }
        NSLog(@"error: %@", FORMAT(@"Echo server started on port %hu", [listenSocket localPort]));
        isRunning = YES;
    }
    else
    {
        // Stop accepting connections
        [listenSocket disconnect];

        // Stop any client connections
        NSUInteger i;
        for(i = 0; i < [connectedSockets count]; i++)
        {
            [[connectedSockets objectAtIndex:i] disconnect];
        }
        NSLog(@"Stopped Echo server");
        isRunning = false;
    }
}

- (void)onSocket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock didAcceptNewSocket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)newSocket
{
    [connectedSockets addObject:newSocket];
}

- (void)onSocket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock didConnectToHost:(NSString *)host port:(UInt16)port
{
    NSLog(FORMAT(@"Accepted client %@:%hu", host, port));
    NSString *welcomeMsg = @"Welcome to the AsyncSocket Echo Server\r\n";
    NSData *welcomeData = [welcomeMsg dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    [sock writeData:welcomeData withTimeout:-1 tag:WELCOME_MSG];

    [sock readDataToData:[GCDAsyncSocket CRLFData] withTimeout:READ_TIMEOUT tag:0];
}

- (void)onSocket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock didWriteDataWithTag:(long)tag
{
    if(tag == ECHO_MSG)
    {
        [sock readDataToData:[GCDAsyncSocket CRLFData] withTimeout:READ_TIMEOUT tag:0];
    }
}

- (void)onSocket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock didReadData:(NSData *)data withTag:(long)tag
{
    NSData *strData = [data subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, [data length] - 2)];
    NSString *msg = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:strData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    if(msg)
    {
        NSLog(@"msg %@", msg);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Error converting received data into UTF-8 String");
    }

    // Even if we were unable to write the incoming data to the log,
    // we're still going to echo it back to the client.
    [sock writeData:data withTimeout:-1 tag:ECHO_MSG];
}

- (NSTimeInterval)onSocket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock
  shouldTimeoutReadWithTag:(long)tag
                   elapsed:(NSTimeInterval)elapsed
                 bytesDone:(NSUInteger)length
{
    if(elapsed <= READ_TIMEOUT)
    {
        NSString *warningMsg = @"Are you still there?\r\n";
        NSData *warningData = [warningMsg dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        [sock writeData:warningData withTimeout:-1 tag:WARNING_MSG];

        return READ_TIMEOUT_EXTENSION;
    }

    return 0.0;
}

- (void)onSocket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock willDisconnectWithError:(NSError *)err
{
    NSLog(FORMAT(@"Client Disconnected: %@:%hu", [sock connectedHost], [sock connectedPort]));
}

- (void)onSocketDidDisconnect:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock
{
    [connectedSockets removeObject:sock];
}
```

I'm not sure about if my implementation is wrong or I should get any kind of permissions granted.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

You should enable its network capability of the App Sandbox

**macOS Catalina Version 10.15.3**:

[image: 111]